# Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity not accepting variable

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Working in a few different domains, that have different naming schema's. So I'm writing a script that goes into each domain, and checks on their group membership.

First thing the script does is ask for the user's last name. Then I use `Get-ADUser` to select the `samaccountname` and tie it to a variable (`samaccountname` is the only name that `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity` parameter accepts).

But when I run the script using the variable for `-Identity` it doesn't find the user. If I type it in manually - it does find the user.

Here's the code:

```
$surname = Read-Host "Users Last Name" 

$fullname = Get-ADUser -filter * | Where-Object {$_.surname -eq $surname} |
            select samaccountname | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $fullname | select name |
  Format-Table -HideTableHeaders
```

The error I get shows that the variable is a string, and it is the correct user that it's searching for, but the error says it can't find that user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Format-*` cmdlets were made for displaying data to a user. Do not use them when further processing of the data is required/intended.

Change

```
... | select samaccountname | Format-Table -HideTableHeaders | Out-String
```

to

```
... | select -Expand samaccountname -First 1
```

and your problem will disappear.

Comment: I figured it had to do with the output of that first variable. Because when I looked at it's .length - the variable was a lot longer than the name of the user, so i figured there was some added spaces in there. 

Thank you very much.